# Create a dataframe from two dictionaries, where their keys are columns and headers and each cell value is a sum of keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dictionaries with key as a string and value as an integer, e.g.:

```
fw_dist = {
"RIGHT_01":100,
"RIGHT_02":200,
"RIGHT_03":300}

rev_dist = {
"LEFT_01":100,
"LEFT_02":200,
"LEFT_03":300}
```

I would like to generate a dataframe where, the keys of each dictionary are columns and headers of the dataframe and the values of each cell is the sum of dictionary keys, e.g.:

```
         LEFT_02 LEFT_01 LEFT_03
RIGHT_03     500     400     600
RIGHT_01     300     200     400
RIGHT_02     400     300     500
```

Is there a neat way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried to iterate through each cell of the df and get the column and index name, get their values from the dictionaries and add them up, but it seems too messy to produce something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way. The idea is convert the dictionaries to Series, then add the elements of the underlying numpy arrays using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
s1 = pd.Series(fw_dist)
s2 = pd.Series(rev_dist)
vals = s1.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1) + s2.to_numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=s1.index, columns=s2.index)
```

Results:

```
          LEFT_01  LEFT_02  LEFT_03
RIGHT_01      200      300      400
RIGHT_02      300      400      500
RIGHT_03      400      500      600
```

Answer (score 2):

A [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions), could do it:

```
data = [[v_fw + v_rev for v_rev in rev_dist.values()] for v_fw in fw_dist.values()]

result = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=rev_dist.keys(), index=fw_dist.keys())

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
          LEFT_01  LEFT_02  LEFT_03
RIGHT_01      200      300      400
RIGHT_02      300      400      500
RIGHT_03      400      500      600
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brute force solution exploiting the itertools library:

```
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fw_dist.keys(), index=rev_dist.keys())
for right, left in product(fw_dist, rev_dist):
    df.loc[left, right] = fw_dist[right] + rev_dist[left]
```

Indeed it is much less elegant if compared with the other solutions, but it can be useful if you can not exploit broadcasting (i.e. if you have to deal with strings, datetime data types etc...).

Answer (score 1):

For me the most pythonic way would involve [numpy.ufunc.outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html)

```
import numpy as np

fw_dist = {
    "RIGHT_01":[100],
    "RIGHT_02":[200],
    "RIGHT_03":[300]}

rev_dist = {
    "LEFT_01":[300],
    "LEFT_02":[200],
    "LEFT_03":[100]}


fw = pd.DataFrame(fw_dist)
rev = pd.DataFrame(rev_dist)


DF = pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(fw,rev).reshape(fw.shape[1],rev.shape[1]), 
                  index=rev.keys(), columns=fw.keys())
```

The output:

```
           RIGHT_01  RIGHT_02  RIGHT_03
LEFT_01       400       300       200
LEFT_02       500       400       300
LEFT_03       600       500       400
```